# What are the chances of each music disc drops from creepers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I play 1.19.3 with some friends and we use music disks as our currency. I was wondering out of all the discs that creepers can drop what are the chances/percentages for each? we want to use these percentages to create the value for each disk.

Comment: Unrelated, but I would recommend using a block that stacks as the base for your economy.

Comment: nah we want something that isn't easy to obtain but isnt impossible, we will rank each disk with a value

Comment: The "issue" I see with this is that it's surprisingly easy to make a farm for music discs, with the hardest item to find for it being a nametag. And using a currency that can be infinitely generated by anyone will lead to hyperinflation real quick. That's why people tend to use diamonds as currency - there is no way to generate them, the only way to get them is to carve them out of the ground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, the wiki page:
https://minecraft.wiki/w/Music_Disc

From this, we know:

> When killed by any skeleton or stray (or wither skeleton if given a bow using commands), a creeper drops a random music disc in addition to its normal drops, with the exceptions of Pigstep, otherside and 5.

The chance of dropping *a* music disk is 100%. Creepers killed in this way will always drop a disk, and the disk is randomly selected.

Pigstep, otherside, 5, and 11 aren't droppable:

- Pigstep comes from nether bastions
- Otherside comes from loot chests
- 5 is crafted from music disk fragments
- 11 is only obtainable in creative.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the chances for each specific music disc, however.